# How to set up git in NAS Server (git, ssh, busybox)

Tags: ssh, git, nas, busybox

I'm trying to set up git using my Synology DS212J NAS Server.

I've been following these instructions:
https://www.wonko.de/2011/01/set-up-git-on-synology-nas.html

But I am very much a beginner with git.

So far I am stuck on the part where it says to:

> Then edit /etc/passwd to enable the user for ssh use. We change he
>   home dir set the login shell:

```
...
user1:x:1026:100::/volume1/home/user1:/bin/sh 
...
```

I keep getting:

```
-ash: user1:x:1026:100::/volume1/home/user1:/bin/sh: not found
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your are just typing the line into the shell, you need to edit the /etc/passwd file as it says (using `vi` or whatever editor you have installed) and add the line (assuming `user`):

```
vi /etc/passed
```

Go to the end of the file, hit <kbd>shift-a</kbd> to get to insert mode, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to start a new line, and paste the following:

```
user1:x:1026:100::/volume1/home/user1:/bin/sh
```

Then <kbd>Esc</kbd> Then save the file:

```
:wq
```