# Set up git on busybox

Tags: git, busybox

I want to set up git on busybox. But I can't find any instructions on doing so. I found [this previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/429352/how-to-set-up-git-in-nas-server-git-ssh-busybox) but the link is dead. What are the basic steps?

Comment: Busybox is a shell, you can’t “set up Git on Busybox”. Are you perhaps also referring to a Synology NAS?

Comment: I’ve updated the link on the old question you linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the instructions using the web archive machine. The latest captures of your link give a cross-reference to a different server, but this appears not to work, either.

However, going back to 2013, the following link works: https://web.archive.org/web/20130828075954/http://www.wonko.de/2010/04/set-up-git-on-synology-nas.html - I didn't check all the snapshots, but this one should be perfectly adequate.